# Knowing GDELT databases and tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gdelt

I'm a bit lost when I have to write the `FROM` statement in Google BigQuery because i do not know which databases and tables are available out there to query. I've seen some queries like these:

```
...
FROM `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`

...
FROM `gdelt-bq.full.events`

...
FROM `gdelt-bq.covid19.onlinenewsgeo`
```

So I assume that there are plenty of those. How o where can I get to know them??. Maybe I do not understand that dot `.` notation (not so used to SQL syntax), is it specifying different tables from databases?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: follow steps in BQ console: Explorer >> ADD DATA >> Pin a project >> Enter project name >> gdelt-bq ; After those steps are done you will see gdelt-bq project in your Explorer and can fully explore/enjoy all the available datasets here

Comment: Great! Tank you so much @MikhailBerlyant , unfortunately there is no project for the GDELT 1.0, but this is just what i needed.